# Chomsky Normal Form Clarification

Tags: complexity-theory, theory, computation

I have been searching for hours but I wasn't able to find out any good explanation of why the first step, which is 'Adding a new start symbol S_0 -> S', is important for converting grammar into Chomsky Normal Form. The only explanation I found from the textbook is that it guarantees that new start variable will not occur on the RHS of any rules. Could someone further elaborate on this? Could the appearance of start symbol on RHS be any bad? Isn't it already handled by removing unit rules? Any clarification would be appreciated :)

Comment: Typo warning: new start variable -> new start symbol

Comment: What does this have to do with programming?

Comment: The start symbol is not allowed to appear on the RHS in Chomsky normal form by definition.

Comment: @harold Yes, that's why we use removing unit rules, don't we? So what's the point of the first step?

Comment: @Ted the start symbol might appear as part of a non-unit rule

Comment: @Ted like A->SB somewhere, which is not valid in CNF btw

Comment: Okay, I think the wikipedia definition kind of messed me up a bit. It uses the word 'may' and sounds like it's possible for start symbol to appear as a non-unit rule on RHS.